# IOS Swift 4 Any to valid json Data

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3

I'm using the MicrosoftAzureMobile framework to get some data from a nodeJs backend of the APP. I have to parse the response which actually is json to my ViewModel. Microsoft provides a function called `invokeApi(someparams)`.

The Problem is, that the completion handler is built like this

```
completion: (data: Any?, response: HTTPURLResponse?, error: Error?) in { ... }
```

When I now try to convert it to `Data` it fails. So I somehow have to figure out how to parse the json to use it in `JSONDecoder.decode()`

The Json of the Data property look something like this:

```
{
content =     {
    createDatetime = "...";
    expireDatetime = "...";
    expiresIn = 1234;
    refreshToken = "...";
    token = "...";
    valid = 1;
};
destination = "...";
hash = ...;
status = successful;
type = "sometype";
}
```

Edit 1:
I tried to convert data by using the following code with no success:

```
let json = data as! Dictionary<String, Any>
let convertedData : Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: json) as Data
print(convertedData as Data)
let tokenServiceResult = try JSONDecoder().decode(TokenServiceResult.self, from: convertedData)
```

But this gives me the following Error:

```
dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.})))
```

Comment: The Model is equal to the Json, if you like to i can also post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`invokeApi()` function already parses the response data to a object of type `Dictionary<String, Any>`. So there is no need to convert it to a Object by using `JsonDecoder().decode()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Decodable protocol:

```
do {
   let myStruct = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyStruct.self, from: data)
      // do what you want here with MyStruct
      // ...
} catch let error {
      // catch error and handled it here
}

struct MyStruct: Decodable {

   let content: Content
   let destination: String
   let hash: String
   let status: Bool
   let type: String
}

struct Content: Decodable {

   let createDatetime: String
   let expireDatetime: String
   let expiresIn: Int
   let refreshToken: String
   let token: String
   let valid: Int
}
```

Comment: I have it like that, my problem is that i didn&amp;#39;t figure out how to convert the data of type any? To the type Data, it cannot cast Dictionary<String, any> which represents the data property of the completion call to Data, which is needed for JsonDecoder.decode()